# Read float and string from txt

Tags: python, file, numpy, io

I have a txt containing both strings and floats (see below) and I need to load the data in a matrix. What is the best way to do it?

Dummy data row:

```
1 2 3.0 4.567 8.910 Data/file.txt
```

Below is my (non working) code. It doesn't return the first three variables, and it does't wrap.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

matrix = []
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
    el = line.split()
    matrix.append(el[0] + el[1] + el[2] + el[3] + el[4] + el[5])
print matrix
```

Comment: ... you usually don't want mixed data types in a numpy matrix

Comment: I know, but i need to work with this beast

Comment: All lines have the same format?

Comment: I don't see what you are wanting to end up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the number of entries the same for each row? If so, I'd recommend using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). Use the `read_csv` function and specify the separator to be `\s+`.

If you want it to be tabular, store it in a Data Frame.

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me.
is the indentation of for loop is typo or not?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

matrix = []
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        el = line.split()
        matrix.append(el[0] + el[1] + el[2] + el[3] + el[4] + el[5])
print matrix
```

output: ['123.04.5678.910Data/file.txt']

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) with [`dtype=None`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html#choosing-the-data-type):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.genfromtxt('input.txt', dtype=None)
array((1, 2, 3.0, 4.567, 8.91, 'Data/file.txt'), 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8'), ('f5', 'S13')])
```